# Как добавить нули в начале числа

Tags: visual-c++

```
void to_binary(int x)
{
    while (x)
    {
        a4 = x % 2;
        x /= 2;
        new_b += a4 * pow(10, g);
        g++;
    }
}
```

Написал функцию перевода числа в бинарную систему счисления, но есть одно но, если число начинается с нуля, например, 0011, то мне в консоли видно только 11, можно ли пофиксить эту проблему, я думал через вектор, но мы его еще не проходили

Comment: `pow(10, g)` — какой ужас...

Comment: а почему она void?

Comment: а с чего вы взяли, что это проблема? Десятичное число 3 вы ведь записываете как 3, а не как 0003.

Comment: может и int и вернуть значения new_b, но это роли не меняет, а на счет pow, g в начале я задал значения 0

Comment: Михайло Куриця, вообще оно не int должно возвращать, а бинарную строку. Большое число из диапазона значений int не влезет в представленную двоичной записью переменную int.

Comment: @Эникейщик у меня задача перевести число в прямой, обратный и модифицированный код, так вот, в обратном коде биты числа (отрицательного) инвертируются (1 на 0 и 0 на 1), и для демонстациы знака "-" мне нужно в начале числа указать "1 "и преподаватель не принял работу, потому что нули в начале не указываются

Comment: @xmikex а если указать long long int?

Comment: unsigned long long подойдёт для двоичных чисел до 524 287 в десятичном формате.